# How to fix error while downloading excel in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am getting error while downloading data in excel sheet in codeigniter php.  The error is getting when the data is more. can someone help me to fix the error.

The error I am getting is as follows :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: PHPExcel/Worksheet.php

Line Number: 1674
```

below is the code

```
for($q = 0,$x = 0;$q < count($data['question']),$x < count($data['details']);$q++,$x++)
            {   
                $z = 0;     
                foreach ($data['details'] as $key => $value)
                {
                    $letter = "C";
                    $letter_rating = "B";
                    $k= 4 + $z;
                    for($i = 0;$i< count($data['details'][$x]);$i++)
                    {
                        if($data['details'][$x][$i]['rating'] == 1)
                        {

                            foreach ($data['selected_demo'] as $value1) 
                            {
                                for($m = 0;$m < count($data['demo_statements']);$m++)
                                {

                                    if ($value1 == $data['demo_statements'][$m]->demo_question_no) 
                                    {
                                    //echo "value ".$value1;
                                    //echo "question_no ".$data['demo_statements'][$m]->demo_question_no;
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);  

                                    //echo '<pre>';print_r($value[$m]);
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {
                                            //echo $m;
                                            //echo $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]];                
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;  
                                        }
                                    }                           
                                }
                                // exit;
                                for($a = 0;$a < count($data['extra_demo']);$a++)
                                {   
                                    if($value1 == $data['extra_demo'][$a]->demo_id)
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer = $data['extra_demo'][$a]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);
                                        //echo count($thead);
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;          
                                        }                                                                                               
                                    }
                                }               
                            }                                                       
                        }                                                                                                                           
                    }
                    //exit;
                    $letter = "C";
                    $letter_rating = "B";
                    $k= 5 + $z; 
                    for($i = 0;$i< count($data['details'][$x]);$i++)
                    {
                        if($data['details'][$x][$i]['rating'] == 2)
                        {

                            foreach ($data['selected_demo'] as $value1) 
                            {
                                for($m = 0;$m < count($data['demo_statements']);$m++)
                                {
                                    if ($value1 == $data['demo_statements'][$m]->demo_question_no) 
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);
                                        //echo count($thead);   
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {                                       
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;  
                                        }                                                                   
                                    }       
                                }
                                for($a = 0;$a < count($data['extra_demo']);$a++)
                                {   
                                    if($value1 == $data['extra_demo'][$a]->demo_id)
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer = $data['extra_demo'][$a]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);
                                        //echo count($thead);
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;  
                                        }                                                                                                               
                                    }       
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //exit;
                    $letter = "C";
                    $letter_rating = "B";
                    $k =6 + $z;
                    for($i = 0;$i< count($data['details'][$x]);$i++)
                    {
                        if($data['details'][$x][$i]['rating'] == 3)
                        {   

                            foreach ($data['selected_demo'] as $value1) 
                            {
                                for($m = 0;$m < count($data['demo_statements']);$m++)
                                {
                                    if ($value1 == $data['demo_statements'][$m]->demo_question_no) 
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);  
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {                                       
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;      
                                        }                                                                                       
                                    }                               
                                }
                                for($a = 0;$a < count($data['extra_demo']);$a++)
                                {   
                                    if($value1 == $data['extra_demo'][$a]->demo_id)
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer = $data['extra_demo'][$a]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;  
                                        }                                                                                                           
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $letter = "C";
                    $k = 7 + $z;
                    for($i = 0;$i< count($data['details'][$x]);$i++)
                    {
                        if($data['details'][$x][$i]['rating'] == 4)
                        {

                            foreach ($data['selected_demo'] as $value1) 
                            {
                                for($m = 0;$m < count($data['demo_statements']);$m++)
                                {
                                    if ($value1 == $data['demo_statements'][$m]->demo_question_no) 
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);  
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {                                       
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;      
                                        }                                                                                       
                                    }                       
                                }
                                for($a = 0;$a < count($data['extra_demo']);$a++)
                                {   
                                    if($value1 == $data['extra_demo'][$a]->demo_id)
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer = $data['extra_demo'][$a]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;      
                                        }                                                                                                       
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $letter = "C";
                    $k = 8 + $z;
                    for($i = 0;$i< count($data['details'][$x]);$i++)
                    {
                        if($data['details'][$x][$i]['rating'] == 5)
                        {       
                            foreach ($data['selected_demo'] as $value1) 
                            {

                                for($m = 0;$m < count($data['demo_statements']);$m++)
                                {
                                    if ($value1 == $data['demo_statements'][$m]->demo_question_no) 
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer =$data['demo_statements'][$m]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);  
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {                                       
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;      
                                        }                                                                   
                                    }                       
                                }
                                for($a = 0;$a < count($data['extra_demo']);$a++)
                                {   
                                    if($value1 == $data['extra_demo'][$a]->demo_id)
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST['language'])){
                                            $language = $_POST['language'];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $language = 1;
                                        }
                                        if($language == 1){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->simplified_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 2){
                                            $answer =$data['extra_demo'][$a]->traditional_chinese_answer; 
                                        }
                                        else if($language == 3){
                                            $answer = $data['extra_demo'][$a]->english_answer;
                                        }
                                        $thead = explode("_",$answer);
                                        for($t = 0;$t < count($thead);$t++)
                                        {
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$k, $data['details'][$x][$i][$thead[$t]]);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                                            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($letter.$k)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);   
                                            $letter++;  
                                        }                                                                                           
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $z = $z + 7;
                }
            }
```

the line where the error is getting in phpexcel is as follows

```
         $upperLeft = $aReferences[0];
```

Comment: someone please help to fix the above error

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're trying to access to a non-existent array item.
You must validate with an

```
if (isset($variable){
    foreach ($variable as $key => $value) 
    { ... }
}
```

Can you post your code?

Comment: Well, at least show the part where you are getting the error: PHPExcel/Worksheet.php line 1674, and also the for/foreach/while cycle

Comment: $aReferences[0] is not defined. You should check what's inside $aReferences variable, and what should be inside. Try a print_r($aReferences) before that line.

Comment: i have printed and it is getting as Array ( [0] => A1 [1] => B1 [2] => C1 [3] => D1 [4] => E1 [5] => F1 [6] => G1 )